# How to convert a NSString to a NSDate with these formats:

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
NSString *dateStr = "09/02/2015 04:51:00 p. m.";
```

I want to convert `*dateStr` to date with this format:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yy'"];
```

And make it look like this :

```
NSString *finalString = "09/02/2015";
```

Comment: First, convert the `NSString` to a `NSDate`, then format the result using what ever format you want

Comment: how to deal with " p. m."